# Acceptance tests and computed properties

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I'm having some issues running an acceptance test where a DOM click fires off an update to a computed property that makes an update to the DOM.

I dumbed down my issue with [this demo repo](https://github.com/odoe/ember-acceptance-test-demo).

I have a basic template

```
<!-- app/templates/application.hbs -->
<a href='#' {{action 'upperNames' 'upper'}}>Show UPPER</a>
<div class="name-container">
  {{#each names as |name|}}
  <p>{{name}}</p>
  {{/each}}
</div>
```

The action hits a Controller that simply sets some props and triggers the computed property

```
// app/controllers/application.js
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  fakeService: Ember.inject.service('fake'),
  update: null,
  names: Ember.computed('fakeService.names.@each', 'update', function() {
    var names = this.get('fakeService.names');
    if (!names || !this.update) {
      return null;
    }
    return names.map(name => name.toUpperCase() + ' - ' + this.update);
  }),
  actions: {
    upperNames: function(update) {
      // I'd normall update this service via a different component
      // but do it here to simplify sample
      Ember.run(() => {
        this.get('fakeService').set('upper', update);
        this.set('update', update);
      });
    }
  }
});
```

The app works fine, as intended.

If I try to run an acceptance test though, it always fails

```
test('click and display names', function(assert) {
  visit('/');
  click('a[href=#]');
  andThen(function() {
    waitFor(function() {
      assert.equal(find('.name-container').children().length, 4);
    });
  });
});
```

This is the output in HTML runner

```
// test failure
failed@ 1033 ms
Expected:   4
Result:     0
```

I even set a ridiculously long timeout and clicked on the link in the app that shows up on my test page and get no results. I can see all the console logs from the controller and the service, but no DOM updates happen.

I'm guessing I'm just not familiar enough with QUnit or acceptance tests with ember-cli and I'm doing something wrong, but I'm not sure.

Any guidance in the right direction would be helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: Would something like this work? https://github.com/toranb/ember-cli-test-helpers/blob/master/tests/acceptance/wait-for-test.js#L25-L27

Comment: Thanks, that seems to have gotten me a little closer, except now I get the following error. "Assertion Failed: You have turned on testing mode, which disabled the run-loop's autorun." It occurs from this line https://github.com/odoe/ember-acceptance-test-demo/blob/master/tests/acceptance/user-can-display-names-test.js#L31. I tried to wrap the assert in Ember.run(), but still same issue. Appreciate the helpers.

Comment: Thanks, I'm updating this comment, as I changed the "defaultWaitForTimeout" to 1 and even 2 and those errors went away, but the results returned by my test for DOM elements are still 0. So it seems like the DOM updates don't happen when the computed property changes.

Comment: Inside the upperNames action you need to wrap anything that does a "set" in Ember.run. Give that a try and let me know if it works for you now :)

Comment: Thanks, but that still didn't work, still same test failuer. I even tried it around each individual "set" and also in the service to check, still no DOM updates. It just seems so odd. Thanks for the help though, I wasn't familiar with Ember.run

Comment: what if you take out the code inside that action -do you STILL get the "autorun" error? (trying to understand if that method is to blame or if it's something else)

Comment: I'm sorry, I couldn't update that original comment. The autorun error went away after I increased the timeout to "defaultWaitForTimeout" to 1 second since my dummy service was set up for 0.5 seconds and I noticed in docs that was default of the waitFor method. After increasing the timeout, no more errors, but the test still fails.